# Pymongo update_one not working in for loop

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have those documents in a collection:

```
{'name': 'Document 1', 'filename': 'Document 1', 'extension': 'pdf', 'filepath': '/mnt/Document 1.pdf', 'origin': 'DB'},
{'name': 'Document 1', 'filename': 'Document 1', 'extension': 'txt', 'filepath': '/mnt/Document 1.txt', 'origin': 'DB'},
{'name': 'Document 2', 'filename': 'Document 2', 'extension': 'pdf', 'filepath': '/mnt/Document 2.pdf', 'origin': 'DB'}
```

When i do something like:

```
query = {'name': 'Document 1', 'extension': 'txt', 'origin': 'DB'}
update = {'$set': {'filepath': '/something/Document 1.txt'}}
document.update_one(
            query, update
            )
```

it works great. But then I have a file that contains:

```
/house/away/Document 1.pdf
/house/away/Document 1.txt
/house/away/Document 2.pdf
```

and I try to do:

```
mongo_client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
print(mongo_client)

db = mongo_client.some_test

document = db.document

file = open('file', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    name = os.path.basename(line).rsplit('.',1)[0]
    extension = os.path.basename(line).split('.')[-1].rstrip('\n')
    new_path = line.rstrip('\n')
    query = {'name': name, 'extension': extension, 'origin': 'DB'}
    update = {'$set': {'filepath': new_path}}
    document.update_one(
        query, update
        )
```

it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you post the code which is before `document = db.document`? I am guessing that you might not have created the connection properly.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I just updated with the connection. The thing is, when I do it without the for loop, everything works fine, so I don't think there is a problem with the connection.

Comment: You are doing it the write way. Could you print the value of `name`, `extension` and `new_path`? Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @ngShravil.py it seems everything is working fine. when i print extension, name and new_path I get:
pdf
Document 1
/house/away/Document 1.pdf
txt
Document 1
/house/away/Document 1.txt
pdf
Document 2
/house/away/Document 2.pdf

Comment: Everything is working fine, I even wrote a program and created a collection similar to yours, it works fine. Just check once, before and after running the python file, whether the content of collection is same or different by running `db.collection.find()`.